# sqlite3 database online storage

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

As you might see from my previous questions i'm making an iOS app at the moment for school, I need to store the db online so I can reach it from a website. I can't use Icloud because i'll have to create an android app after this one. (i know i could have made a hybrid app , but i wanted to go obj-c).So my question here is : 
`What is the easiest way to do it and which storage service is it best to use (free one)?`

i'm using an sqlite3 db.

I browsed the web trying to find easy examples , but i can't find any, so i'm trying my luck with you guys , who already helped me multiple times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is mandatory to use sqlite? if not take a look to this article http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more

Comment: all the ways interacting directly to a remote database is not a common practice in iOS, the *best* approach (more used) is to create web services layer between your database and the app

Comment: Generally speaking, you should create a REST service to serve your data.

Comment: Well , it wasn't mandatory , but i already made huge part of my application with sqlite , and i would like to keep it with sqlite3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have server than create Web Services for that return Data according to your need. So , you dont have to maintain data in sqlite instead of all data will be managed on server side. Plus point to do this, same web services will be useful in android also.

You can either use .net or PHP or whatever web development language to create web services.